How to run a video in flutter windows application (flutter: Error initializing video: UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented.)
I am trying to display a video as a screen saver, but it is not running on my flutter application[Windows (desktop)]. and console is throwing error as

flutter: Error initializing video: UnimplementedError: init() has not been implemented.

here's my code :
import 'dart:async';  // For Timer functionality
import 'dart:io';     // For File access
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: VideoPlayerFromFile(),
    );
  }
}

class VideoPlayerFromFile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoPlayerFromFileState createState() => _VideoPlayerFromFileState();
}

class _VideoPlayerFromFileState extends State<VideoPlayerFromFile> {
  VideoPlayerController? _controller;  // Change to nullable
  bool _isBlackScreen = false;
  Timer? _blackScreenTimer;  // Timer to trigger the black screen every 15 minutes

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeVideoPlayer();
    _startBlackScreenTimer();  // Start the timer for the 15-minute gap
  }

  // Function to initialize the video player
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayer() async {
    String filePath = r'C:\videodata\video.mp4';  // Ensure correct path with 'r' to escape backslashes

    // Check if the file exists
    if (await File(filePath).exists()) {
      // Initialize the video player controller with the file path
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(filePath));

      // Wait for the video to initialize
      await _controller!.initialize().then((_) {
        // Once the video is initialized, update the state to start playing
        setState(() {
          _controller!.play();  // Automatically start the video
        });
      }).catchError((error) {
        print("Error initializing video: $error");
      });
    } else {
      // File does not exist, print error message
      print('File does not exist at path: $filePath');
    }
  }

  // Function to start the 15-minute timer for the black screen
  void _startBlackScreenTimer() {
    _blackScreenTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 15), (timer) {
      _showBlackScreen();
    });
  }

  // Function to show the black screen for 7 seconds
  void _showBlackScreen() {
    setState(() {
      _isBlackScreen = true;
    });

    // Pause the video during the black screen
    _controller?.pause();

    // After 7 seconds, remove the black screen and resume the video
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7), () {
      setState(() {
        _isBlackScreen = false;
        _controller?.play();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    _blackScreenTimer?.cancel();  // Cancel the timer when the widget is disposed
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Play Video with Black Screen Interval'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Show the black screen if triggered, otherwise display the video
        child: _isBlackScreen
            ? Container(
          color: Colors.black,  // Black screen
        )
            : _controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized
            ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller!.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller!),
        )
            : Text('Loading video... or File not found'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
            // Play or pause the video depending on its current state
                    if (_controller!.value.isPlaying) {
                      _controller!.pause();
                    } else {
                      _controller!.play();
                    }
                  });
              },
            child: Icon(
          _controller!.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      )
          : null,  // Hide the button if the controller isn't initialized
    );
  }
}


Expecting a video to be display run in flutter application

This error occured because of the video_player packages do not support Windows yet. You can see in the pubdev, that this package only supports:

Android
iOS
MacOS
Web

You can see the compability below the package title

And in the description


Recommendation
After a quick research i found video_player_win a video player
package for Windows, this package actively maintained by the author,
maybe you want try this for video player on Windows.


Congrats! if you feel helped by my answer, please consider to mark this as accepted answer. Thanks!
